# How to remove the white space on the top of the following table?

Tags: spacing, longtable, best-practices, preview, standalone

How to remove the white space on the top of the following table?

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=0pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}


\newcolumntype{A}[2]{%
    >{\minipage{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-#2\arrayrulewidth}\vspace\tabcolsep}%
    c%
    <{\vspace\tabcolsep\endminipage}%
}

\newcommand\correction[1]{%
    \abovedisplayshortskip=#1\baselineskip\relax
    \belowdisplayshortskip=#1\baselineskip\relax
    \abovedisplayskip=#1\baselineskip\relax
    \belowdisplayskip=#1\baselineskip\relax
}

\rowcolors{1}{cyan!20}{white}%
\arrayrulewidth=1pt\relax
%\topskip=0pt\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*2{>{\arraybackslash\correction{-1}\strut\[}A{0.4}{1.5}<{\]\strut}|}}\hline
f(x) & f'(x)\\\hline
c & 0\\\hline
x^n & nx^{n-1}\\\hline
\ln x & \frac{1}{x}\\\hline
e^x & e^x\\\hline
a(x)b(x) & a'(x)b(x)+a(x)b'(x)\\\hline
\frac{a(x)}{b(x)} & \frac{a'(x)b(x)-a(x)b'(x)}{b^2(x)}\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

### Bonus:

As I want to be a best practitioner, please kindly try to optimize, simplify, improve my code above.

Comment: I do not have a comment for your code, but one or two for the result: since the first line seems to be a table header, I would suggest making it stand out more (eg. by coloring it differently, or by having a double line below it); also see, for example, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Professional_tables, for suggestions about using *less* border lines on your tables.

Comment: @nplatis: Please show me your idea with code and you will see the problem when using `booktabs` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The white space comes from `\LTpre`, add the following line to your preamble after `\usepackage{longtable}`:

```
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
```

Also `\LTpost` could be set to `0pt`, but `standalone` seems to remove this space at the end of the page.

Comment: Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: @FriendlyGhost The space is usually skipped at the start of a new page inside a document. But the document here uses class `standalone`, a special case, where the answer is not so clear, because there are arguments for both. Ask the author of class `standalone` for clarification.